# In spark "--executor-core" represents logical cores or physical cores?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have a machine with 16 cores and each having 2 logical processors.
So if I set `--num-executors` as 2 and `--executor-core` as 3.
Then in each node there will be 2 executors using 3 cores each. So each executor can run in parallel (`2*3=6`) 6 tasks. Now does spark create separate threads within each core to use logical processors that are present in  each core?
SO my question is this parallelism occurs at physical core level or logical processor level?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, the parallelism occurs at the logical processor level, not the physical core level.

When you set **--num-executors** as 2 and **--executor-core** as 3, each executor will use 3 logical processors, and since each core has 2 logical processors, this means that each executor will use 1.5 physical cores.

Spark uses a concept called "task slots" to manage parallelism within each executor. Each task slot represents a logical processor, and multiple tasks can be executed concurrently within a single executor as long as there are available task slots.

So in your example, each executor would have 3 task slots (or logical processors), and up to 6 tasks can run concurrently within each executor, depending on the availability of task slots.

To summarize, Spark's parallelism occurs at the *logical processor level*, and it uses task slots to manage parallelism within each executor. Multiple tasks can be executed concurrently within a single executor as long as there are available task slots.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how each executor would use 1.5 physical cores ?